# Wordpress 3.5.1: plugin for multiple author

Tags: wordpress

Is there any good wp plugin by which I could assign single post to many authors/users?

After search I found [Multiple Authors](http://txfx.net/wordpress-plugins/multiple-authors/) but after activate I select some authors for a single post & save but it manage user as **terms** not normal user.

> For now I created a special category and moved posts under that
>   category & showing to all authors.

Answer (score 0):

I used to used Co-Authors Plus plugin for the same..

See if you find it any useful..

Link : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/co-authors-plus/installation/

After you add multiple authors using this plugin. It will show something like, Posted by "Author 1" and "Author 2"..

Very good plugin with active development.